# Parallel execution is failing. its executing test successfully on one session and the other session, no actions being performed

Tags: selenium, parallel-processing, testng

I am trying to execute tests in parallel using testng and selenium.  when I triggered the tests, its executing successfully on one session, and the other session it just hangs.. am seeing following error in logs.

I tried using methods/classes/tests as parallel options in testng.xml.  its same issue in all cases.

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: 'PF12FNSG20HE', ip: '146.27.24.164', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:605)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:294)
        at AEMSites.Base.getScreenShot(Base.java:186)
        at resources.TestListeners.onTestFailure(TestListeners.java:36)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1895)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1879)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1292)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My code is as follows:

POM File:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>AEMSites</groupId>
  <artifactId>ChevronECOM</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ChevronECOM</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Selenium -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency> 
 <!-- TestNG -->
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
          <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
          <version>6.8</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

    <!-- Extent Reports --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>2.41.2</version>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
    <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
     <version>2.4</version>
 </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <configuration>
        <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        <properties>
   <property>
     <name>parallel</name>
     <value>methods</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>threadCount</name>
     <value>2</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
     <value>2</value>
   </property>
 </properties>
           </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Test Ng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name=" test suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">
<listeners>
<listener class-name="resources.TestListeners"/>
<listener class-name="ExtentReportsChevron"/>
<listener class-name="resources.RetryListenerClass"/>
</listeners>
  <test name="Chrome Tests" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">
       <classes>
      <class name="AEMSites.TechronCleanHomePageTests"/>
      <class name="AEMSites.TechronCleanContactUsPageTests"/>
      <class name="AEMSites.TechronCleanFAQTests"/>
      <class name="AEMSites.TechronCleanWhereToBuyPageTests"/>
     </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
 </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

My Tests:

```
package AEMSites;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import AEMSites.pageObjects.TechronCleanHomePage;
import AEMSites.pageObjects.TechronCleanSearchResultsPage;



public class TechronCleanHomePageTests extends Base
{

    TechronCleanHomePage tch;
    TechronCleanSearchResultsPage tcsrp;
    //public static String experience;

    @BeforeMethod

    public void HomePageNavigation(Method method) throws Throwable
    {
        //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\hpak\\ChevronECOM\\Variables.properties");
        //prop.load(fis);
        //experience=prop.getProperty("experience");

        System.out.println("Test Executing is: " + method.getName());
        driver=initializeDriver();
        System.out.println("step1" + driver);

        System.out.println("step1" + url);
        driver.get(url);
        System.out.println("step2");


        System.out.print("Expericene in test method is"+experience);

        if(experience.equalsIgnoreCase("mobile"))
        {
            System.out.println("In Home page tests before method in mobile");
            tch = new TechronCleanHomePage(driver);
            tch.getMobileHamburgerMenu().click();
        }

        else
        {
            driver.manage().window().maximize();

        }
    }


    @Test(groups = {"HomePage"})
    public void TC_014_VerifyProductsLinkOnHomePage() throws InterruptedException
    {
        tch = new TechronCleanHomePage(driver);
        System.out.println("In test case method, experience is "+experience);
        if(experience.equalsIgnoreCase("mobile"))
        {
            tch.getProducts_mobile().click();
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("In desktop method");
            tch.getProducts().click();

        }
        Assert.assertTrue((tch.getCurrentWindowUrl()).contains("products.html"));
    }

    @Test(groups = {"HomePage"})

    public void TC_043_VerifyWhyTechronLinkOnHomePage()
    {

        tch = new TechronCleanHomePage(driver);
        tch.getWhyTechron().click();
        Assert.assertTrue((tch.getCurrentWindowUrl()).contains("why-techron.html"));

    }

    @Test(groups = {"HomePage"})

    public void TC_002_VerifySearchAndVisitProductPage()
    {
        System.out.println("In search test");
        tch = new TechronCleanHomePage(driver);
        tcsrp = new TechronCleanSearchResultsPage(driver);
        tch.getSearchIcon().click();
        tch.getSearchBar().sendKeys("Motor Oil");
        tch.getSearchBar().sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
        try
        {

        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Motor Oil"));
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Search Results"));
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Techron Complete Fuel System Cleaner"));
        }
        catch (Error e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        tcsrp.getProductLink().click();
        try
        {
        Assert.assertTrue((tch.getCurrentWindowUrl()).contains("techron-complete-fuel-system"));
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Concentrate Plus Complete Fuel System Cleaner"));
        }
        catch (Error e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }   
    }

    @Test(groups = {"HomePage"})

    public void TC_012_VerifyProductLineupOnHomePage()
    {
        tch = new TechronCleanHomePage(driver);
        String findproductext=tch.getFindProductText().getText();
        System.out.print("one"+findproductext);
        Assert.assertTrue(findproductext.contains("FIND A PRODUCT"));
        String imagesrc=tch.getImageSource().getAttribute("src");
        System.out.print("two"+imagesrc);
        Assert.assertTrue(imagesrc.contains("/content/dam"));
        tch.getImageSource().click();
        String imagesrcafterclick=tch.getImageSource().getAttribute("src");
        System.out.print("three"+imagesrcafterclick);
        Assert.assertTrue(imagesrcafterclick.contains("/content/dam"));
        Assert.assertTrue(tch.getLearnMoreBtnOnPrdLineUp().isDisplayed());


    }


    @Test(groups = {"HomePage"})

    public void TC_041_VerifyWhereToBuyOnHomePage()
    {
        tch = new TechronCleanHomePage(driver);
        tch.getWhereToBuy().click();
        Assert.assertTrue((tch.getCurrentWindowUrl()).contains("where-to-buy.html"));

    }

    @Test(groups = {"HomePage"})

    public void TC_046_VerifyFAQLinkOnHomePage()
    {
        tch = new TechronCleanHomePage(driver);
        tch.getFAQ().click();
        Assert.assertTrue((tch.getCurrentWindowUrl()).contains("faq.html"));

    }

    @Test(groups = {"Footer"})

    public void TC_003_VerifyContactUsLinkOnFooter()
    {
        tch = new TechronCleanHomePage(driver);
        tch.getContactUs().click();
        System.out.println("Current Window url is"+tch.getCurrentWindowUrl());

        Assert.assertTrue((tch.getCurrentWindowUrl()).contains("contact-us.html"));
    }


@Test(groups = {"HomePage"})

    public void TC_010_VerifyMarketFormOnHomePage() throws InterruptedException
    {
        tch = new TechronCleanHomePage(driver);
        tch.getMarketoFirstName().sendKeys("TestFirst");
        tch.getMarketoLastName().sendKeys("TestLast");
        tch.getMarketoEmail().sendKeys("ignore@gmail.com");
        tch.getMarketoSubmitBtn().click();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        System.out.println("Current Window url is"+tch.getCurrentWindowUrl());
        Assert.assertTrue((tch.getCurrentWindowUrl()).contains("aliId"));
    }

    @Test(groups = {"Footer"})

    public void TC_004_VerifyTermsOfUseLinkOnFooter()
    {
        tch = new TechronCleanHomePage(driver);
        tch.getTermsOfUse().click();
        Assert.assertTrue((tch.getCurrentWindowUrl()).contains("terms-of-use"));
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("terms of use"));

    }

    @Test(groups = {"Footer"})

    public void TC_005_VerifyPrivacyPolicyOnFooter()
    {
        tch = new TechronCleanHomePage(driver);
        tch.getPrivacyPolicy().click();
        Assert.assertTrue((tch.getCurrentWindowUrl()).contains("privacy"));
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("privacy statement"));

    }

    @Test (groups = {"Footer"})
    public void TC_006_VerifyChevronLubricantsLinkOnFooter()
    {
        tch = new TechronCleanHomePage(driver);
        tch.getChevronLubricants().click();
        Assert.assertTrue((tch.getCurrentWindowUrl()).contains("https://www.chevronlubricants.com/"));

    }

    @Test (enabled=false)
    public void VerifyTabItemsOnHomePage()
    {
        List<WebElement> allLinks = ((WebDriver) driver).findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println("In Verify Tab items test");
        System.out.println(allLinks);

        for (WebElement w : allLinks)
        {

            w.click();
            if (((WebDriver) driver).findElement(By.xpath("Element on the page")).isDisplayed())
            {
                System.out.println("Link:"+w.getText()+"is working");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Link:"+w.getText()+"is not working");
            }
            ((WebDriver) driver).navigate().back();//To come back to the Home screen

        }
    }


    @AfterMethod

    public void closeAll()
    {
          //System.out.println("Test:" + result.getMethod().getMethodName()+ " is "+status.toString().toUpperCase());

        driver.quit();
        //driver.close();
        driver=null;
    }

}
```

can someone please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run with

```
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void HomePageNavigation(Method method)
```

And

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void closeAll()
```